# Get templated, template type

Tags: c++, class, templates, types

I am creating a small 'generic' pathfinding class which takes a class type of `Board` on which it will be finding paths,

```
//T - Board class type
template<class T>
class PathFinder
{...}
```

Whereas `Board` is also templated to hold the node type. (so that i can find paths on 2D or 3D vector spaces).

I would like to be able to declare and define a member function for `PathFinder` that will take parameters like so

```
//T - Board class type
PathFinder<T>::getPath( nodeType from, nodeType to);
```

How can I perform the type compatibility for the node type of `T` and `nodeType` that is fed into the function as parameter ?

Comment: nodeType and T are the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you want, give `board` a type member and use that:

```
template<class nodeType>
class board {
  public:
    typedef nodeType node_type;
  // ...
};

PathFinder<T>::getPath(typename T::node_type from, typename T::node_type to);
```

You can also pattern match it if you can't change `board`:

```
template<class Board>
struct get_node_type;
template<class T>
struct get_node_type<board<T> > {
  typedef T type;
};

PathFinder<T>::getPath(typename get_node_type<T>::type from, typename get_node_type<T>::type to);
```

Comment: what is this for?
`template<class Board>
struct get_node_type;`

Comment: @KarthikT You can't partially specialize without that.

Answer (score 3):

You can `typedef` `nodeType` inside class definition:

```
typedef typename T::nodeType TNode;
PathFinder<T>::getPath( TNode from, TNode to);
```